# How to make a docker container directory accesible from host?

Tags: tomcat, docker, volume

I have a tomcat running in a docker container and would like to watch was is going on in the webapps directory from the docker host. Is it possible to do this by mounting a volume without setting up a sshd in the container and without starting a shell inside?

Comment: See the Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mounting volume, you could open a new bash in your running container with **[`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/)**:

```
docker exec -it <id of running container> bash
```

That way, you can directly go to the folder managed by the webapp from within the container.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare some local folder on your host machine as the webapps folder of tomcat.

```
docker run -d -v $(pwd)/webapps:/path/to/tomcat/webapps yourimage/tomcat
```

> Afterwards Tomcat will write to the local folder and you can view it! The existing folder will not be visible as long as the folder is mounted.

You can declare a volume and then start a second container to mount and browse it!

```
docker run -d --name tomcat -v /path/to/tomcat/webapps yourimage/tomcat
docker run -it --volumes-from tomcat yourimage/tomcat bash
```

> Has the advantage that the current folder is copied inside the volume.

Comment: There is already a webapps folder in the image and it has already some content. Of course, this content must be visible both from the container and from the host. What dou you mean with "as long as the folder is mounted"? Isn't it "mounted" during the whole lifetime of the container?

Comment: I don't understand the part with the second container.

Comment: Then copy the contents outside the container and then mount it inside the container: docker cp container:/path/to/tomcat/webapps /local/folder and then mount it docker run -d --name tomcat -v /local/folder:/path/to/tomcat/webapps yourimage/tomcat

Comment: This may be the best solution for you! A docker volume is just a directory on the Docker host. So run your container docker run -d --name tomcat -v /path/to/tomcat/webapps yourimage/tomcat. The containers files will be copied onto the volume at containers start. Run this to get the directory docker inspect -f {{.Volumes}} yourimage/tomcat.