# Update Docker container after making changes to image

Tags: django, docker

I am new to Docker and am experimenting with developing a Django App on Docker.

I have followed the example in this link [here:](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/)

Currently I am developing my app and have made changes to various files within the web directory. For now in order to test my changes I have had to remove all my running containers, stop my docker machine, start my docker machine, attach docker machine, run docker-compose up. This is a timely process and is unproductive especially if I need to keep testing after small changes.

My question is if I make changes to the image (changes in the web directory) how can I update my container to reflect those changes or should I be doing things differently?

How do other people develop using Docker? what are your best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use volumes to map host directory in container's web directory.  Any changes in host directory will be reflected immediately without restarting container. See below post.

[How to make a docker container directory accesible from host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569846/how-to-make-a-docker-container-directory-accesible-from-host)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker-compose up --build` to rebuild the image and container after making changes. It will automatically rebuild and restart any changed containers. There shouldn't be any reason to stop docker machine. If you are using a Mac or Windows PC, you can try the new beta app, which is a bit easier to use than prior versions.

Also see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/

As for best practices, this probably isn't really the right forum unless you have a more specific question.